# how would you generate random integers that are unique from each other in pascal

Tags: delphi, random, integer

I would like to make a program in pascal that chooses 6 random integers between 1 and 49. each number should be unique i.e. you cannot have '8,22'22'32'37'43' because the '22' is repeated.How could I Implement this is in Delphi.

I can get 6 random numbers between 1 - 49 by using the following code.

```
for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin 
    num[i] := random(49) + 1
  end
{next};
```

Comment: A very simple approach would be to first fill a list with all number values from 0 to max-1 and then pick and remove a random one using `random(count(list))`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That would do it. That's Fisher-Yates.

Comment: Then my way with words is more [Pascal'ian](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/04/28/shorter-letter/) than yours ;)

Comment: Sounds like a lottery number generator :)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why the above code isn't what he wants.

Comment: @NickHodges Because there's a chance that the same number might show up more than once.

Comment: @Nick Asker wants sampling without replacement. The code in question implements sampling with replacement.

Comment: Hmm.  Learned something new today.  My understanding was that Delphi's random generation won't repeat until all numbers have been output.

Comment: @Nick RNGs don't do that. They sample from the uniform distribution with replacement. If they did anything else they'd be pretty much useless.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. Put the numbers 1 to 49 into an array.
2. Perform a shuffle on the array.
3. Pull out the first 6 elements.

It's probably not the most efficient way, but it's easy to implement, easy to understand, and, most crucially, easy to reason about the distributional properties of your sampling method.

For the shuffle, use [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle. I implement that like this, in a generic method:

```
procedure TRandomNumberGenerator.Permute<T>(var Values: array of T);
var
  i, Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := Length(Values);
  for i := 0 to Count-2 do
    TGeneric.Swap<T>(Values[i], Values[i + Uniform(Count-i)]);
end;
```

where `Uniform(N)` is the function of my RNG that returns a value drawn from the uniform distribution over `0..N-1`. You could replace that with `Random` in your code. And `TGeneric.Swap<T>` swaps the two elements.

You could modify this to work on an array of integers like so:

```
procedure Swap(var lhs, rhs: Integer);
var
  tmp: Integer;
begin
  tmp := lhs;
  lhs := rhs;
  rhs := tmp;
end;

procedure Permute(var Values: array of Integer);
var
  i, Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := Length(Values);
  for i := 0 to Count-2 do
    Swap(Values[i], Values[i + Random(Count-i)]);
end;
```

Of course, you only need to perform the first six iterations of the loop, so a very efficient version would be like this:

```
function Choose(M, N: Integer): TArray<Integer>;
var
  i: Integer;
  Values: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  Assert(M>0);
  Assert(N>=M);

  SetLength(Values, N);
  for i := 0 to N-1 do
    Values[i] := i+1;

  for i := 0 to Min(M-1, N-2) do
    Swap(Values[i], Values[i + Random(N-i)]);

  Result := Copy(Values, 0, M);
end;
```

You would call this passing 6 and 49:

```
Values := Choose(6, 49);
```

If you were a mad performance freak then I think it would be hard to beat this:

```
type
  TArr6 = array [0..5] of Integer;
  PArr6 = ^TArr6;
  TArr49 = array [0..48] of Integer;

const
  OrderedArr49: TArr49 = (
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
    35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
  );

function Choose6: TArr6;
var
  i: Integer;
  Values: TArr49;
begin
  Values := OrderedArr49;
  for i := 0 to high(Result) do begin
    Swap(Values[i], Values[i + Random(Length(Values)-i)]);
  end;
  Result := PArr6(@Values)^;
end;
```

I should say that I doubt that performance would be the driving factor here.

Comment: I would take the Non-Pointers version any day.

Comment: @WarrenP I was trying to cover all the bases!!  ;-)

Comment: If I use High I also use Low -> `for i := Low( Result ) to High( Result ) do`

Answer (score 8):

I think for a simple solution, considering the relatively small number of values you want versus the number of possible values, you could just brute force it.

If this were Perl or PHP, I'd use associative arrays, but generics are fine too:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  numbers: TList<Integer>;
  num: Integer;
  output: String;
begin
  numbers := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    // We need six integers
    for i := 1 to 6 do
    begin
      // Generate a "random" integer
      num := Random(49) + 1;
      // Keep going until it isn't in our list
      while numbers.Contains(num) do
      begin
        num := Random(49) + 1;
      end;
      // Add it to the list
      numbers.Add(num);
    end;
    // Display the list
    output := '';
    for num in numbers do
    begin
      output := output + IntToStr(num) + ':';
    end;
    ShowMessage(output);
  finally
    numbers.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This solution may stir up some debate because some may think it's theoretically possible that this will never return, but considering Delphi's PRNG, this won't be the case.

Comment: Given how easy it is to just shuffle a list of integers, I would just do that instead.