# How to select five random non-repeating buttons and copy them to panel1?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7

I have 20 buttons that are created automatically when the program starts. How to select five random non-repeating buttons and copy them to the Panel1 component?

[image]

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1:TForm1;
  but:array[1..9] of TButton;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 20 do
  begin
    but[i] := TButton.Create(Form1);
    but[i].Parent := Form1;
    but[i].Caption := IntToStr(i);
    but[i].Font.Size := 26;
    but[i].Width := 50;
    but[i].Height := 50;
    but[i].Left := 50 + Round(i mod 3)*but[i].Width;
    but[i].Top := 50 + Round(i / 3)*but[i].Height;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I suggest you look in Delphi-7 Help, first for arithmetic operators `div` and `mod` and then,  the `divmod()` procedure. You can omit the `Round()` functions you now have. Then also consider a small change to the formulae for calculation of left and top properties, to improve the layout of the buttons.

Answer (score 6):

The algorithm is like this:

1. Hold references to the buttons in an array.
2. Perform a uniform shuffle of the array, for instance using the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.
3. Choose the first 5 items from the array.

You can optimise this if you wish by interrupting the shuffle after 5 iterations of its loop, because the first 5 items have already been chosen by that point. However, that's probably not necessary for such a small array.

There are many implementations of Fisher-Yates around, although beware that a large proportion are implemented incorrectly! Correct implementations abound also, for instance here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20361298/505088

You could do worse than use the spring4d library for this task.

As far as copying buttons goes, create new buttons and copy over the properties that you need. It may be easier to think of this job as actually choosing 5 random numbers between 1 and 20, and then creating 5 buttons captioned with those numbers. Again, that's just a shuffle of the numbers.

If you want to put 20 items in an array, you'll want to make sure the array is large enough. Your array can hold 9 items, but you try to put 20 in.